# How to stop system default windows from randomly appearing on my OMRON NB5Q-TW01B HMI?

Tags: controls, plc

I have an OMRON NB5Q-TW01B HMI that seems to work fine with my control system design. However, there are 9 system default windows that cannot be deleted on NB-Designer.

Any one of these system default windows will randomly pop up on the HMI interface and can only be removed by clicking the reset button on the back of the HMI. Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: I think this question would be more at home on Serverfault (https://serverfault.com/)